# In express.js, when I use promises, do I need to include reject() in the executor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the situation that we do not deal with reject, must we include reject in the promise executor?

for example:

```
 new promise ((res)=>{
   res(a);
 })
```

Comment: Have a look at this:  https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970

Comment: Could you re-word your title?

Comment: @DavidFarrugia, thanks it is a good article!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that a promise will never be rejected, adding a rejection handler is not necessary. E.g. it's obvious this will never be rejected and adding a rejection handler would be plain silly:

```
Promise.resolve("abc")
    .then(result => console.log(result));
```

In all other cases, not providing a rejection handler is pretty much the same as not wrapping an error-throwing piece of code in `try`-`catch`. It might be intentional, of course, but bear in mind that node.js will treat unhandled promise rejections as if they were uncaught errors: by terminating the node.js process. That's what it says on the console when an unhandled promise rejection occurs:

> (node:7741) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

So, summing up:

- skip rejection handlers when you know for a fact a rejection is impossible,
- skip rejection handlers when you require the application be terminated upon rejection (in future versions of Node.js),
- write rejection handlers in all other cases.

EDIT (the question became clearer after the edits were made, hence my update to the answer):

As for including the `reject()` call in the promise executor, no, you do not need to add it. Again though, you have to make sure that the internal logic guarantees that `resolve()` will always be called.

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary, no, but it's not a very elegant way to handle errors - if an error is thrown whilst your promise is pending, you'll want to take some other action and reject the promise, letting the user know what's wrong.

Have a look at [MDN Promise Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), they explain the concept of handling errors in Promises pretty well!